# Ember application memory leak

Tags: memory-management, ember.js, memory-leaks, ember-data, ember-cli

I am investigating a memory leak issue in an Ember (using Ember data) application. The issue happens in my tests where I call reset() on the Ember application after each test has finished. It turned out that the reset() doesn't remove all the references to **container** before creating a new one, which resulted in many containers hanging in the memory, the leakage is significant because a container keeps all the controllers and routes in cache.

I then use Chrome Dev Tool to profile the memory and one of the retaining paths that I got is:
`controller:product/create in 27138485
   cache in Container @27017929
     container in @26910113
       13 in @26702605
         code in function() @26588769
           adapterFor in @26498509
             prototype in function() @26491127
               Store in Class @26491123
                 DS in Window / localhost:8889/tests @26461671`

Has there anyone experienced such memory issue with Ember/Ember data as well?

I have tried something like below as well:

```
function setup() {
    var app = Application.createWithMixins({
       rootElement: '#ember-testing'
    });
    app.setupForTesting();
    app.injectTestHelpers();
    return app;
}
```

before each test to setup a new application

and

```
function teardown() {
    Ember.run(this.App, 'destroy');
}
```

to destroy the application after each test. But still got many references to container created by previous test.

Comment: You should be destroying the app after each test not reseting, something along the lines of `Ember.run(app, app.destroy);`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Kitler, i have tried to destroy the app and create new one for each test but it still not removing references to previous containers.  I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: I've just noticed that my app with Ember 1.13.6 actually seems to leak its components on every route transition.  I made a little toy app that only lets you transition from one (super-simple) route to another (equally-simple) route, and it seems that the DOM node count in chrome's timeline tools goes up by about 20 each transition.  If you transition routes in your test, maybe that's causing your issue?

Comment: @ArtHare Did you ever figure out a solution to the transition issue.

Comment: Update to a newer version of Ember.  I believe the latest version of 1.13 had it fixed, if you can't go to a cutting-edge version.
@Kauthon